# Skeleton framework - four columns site

Tags: css, responsive-design

i just started to build a website index.html which has a four columns. For some reason columns breaks down in tablet size when i test and resize browser. (last column just drops down)

What i have done wrong :-)

Here's my simple code so far:

```
    <header><!-- Header osuus -->

    <div class="four columns"> <a href="http://www.nhl.com"><img src="images/logo.png"   
width="220" height="33" class="scale-with-grid" style="margin-top: 119px;"></a></div>

    <!-- Navikaatio -->

    <div class="eleven columns offset-by-one">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Yritys</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Työkalut</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Ylläpito</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Kehitys</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Pilvi</a></li>
                </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>

    </header><!-- Header päättyy -->


            <div class="section">

                <div class="four columns">
                <div class="inner">
                dfdfgdfgdf dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgd dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgfdgdf
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="four columns">
                <div class="inner">
                dfdfgdfgdf dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgd dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgfdgdf
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="four columns">
                <div class="inner">
                dfdfgdfgdf dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgd dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgfdgdf
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="four columns">
                <div class="inner">
                dfdfgdfgdf dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgd dfg dfg dfg dfgdfgfdgdf
                </div>
                </div>


            </div>  

</div><!-- container -->


css for inner class:

.inner {
height: 339px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #707070;
margin-top: 105px;
text-align:left;
}
```

// Mika

Comment: Have you tried using "display:inline;" and/or "float:left" to the .inner? This may solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to wrap the four column divs in a `.container` div. I think that's how Skeleton works isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Skeleton requires you to wrap everything in a container, and all columns in a row. I think this might be your issue. So:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    // columns here
  </div>  
</div>
```